# Elasticsearch Mappings Examples

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have been looking into elasticsearch for a few weeks. Conceptually, I understand most of the capabilities of the JAVA API. The problem I have is with the mappings. My understanding is that for the most part, the field types that you select, in combination with the analyzers, etc, are usually driven by HOW the data will be searched, and what type of queries the developer plans to be run against the data. Are there any practical examples of some elasticsearch mappings and associated queries, that explain WHY the field types/analyzers that were chosen were used? I understand that getting the mappings right is crucial, because if you don't get it right, you have to re-index, so because of that, I know that the mapping is important.

Comment: It's a good question. I have not seen any good examples of real world cases. I have been working on mapping and search for an application and have resorted to ES source code to find out what the ES query language accepts and can do. ES has a lot of documentation, but it is a bit superficial in this area, barely scratches the surface of what you can do.

Comment: I think, You will get your answer related to mapping and related search queries from [Search in Depth](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-in-depth.html) . Though it's not updated with Elasticsearch 5.x mapping. But concept is same.